# How class level lock is acquired

Tags: java, static, synchronization, locking

```
public synchronized int getCountOne() {
        return count++;
 }
```

Like in above code synchronizing on the method is functionally equivalent to having a `synchronized (this) block` around the body of the method. The object "this" doesn't become locked, rather the object "this" is used as the `mutex` and the body is prevented from executing concurrently with other code sections also synchronized on "this."

On similar grounds what is used as a `mutex` when we acquire a class level lock.As in if we have a function

```
public static synchronized int getCountTwo() {
        return count++;
 }
```

obviously two threads can simultaneously obtain locks on getCountOne(object level lock) and getCountTwo(class level lock). So as getCountOne is analogous to

```
public int getCountOne() {
     synchronized(this) {
          return count++;
     }
 }
```

is there an equivalent of getCountTwo? If no what criteria is used to obtain a Class level lock?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> On similar grounds what is used as a mutex when we acquire a class level lock

The class object itself will be used as mutex. The equivalent synchronized block for your `static synchronized` method will look like:

```
public static int getCountTwo() {
     synchronized(ClassName.class) {
          return count++;
     }
}
```

`ClassName` is the name of the class containing that method.

See [JLS Section §8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, **the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class** is used.
>
> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object
>   for which the method was invoked) is used.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Object level locking:**

Object level locking is mechanism when you want to synchronize a non-static method or non-static code block such that only one thread will be able to execute the code block on given instance of the class. This should always be done to make instance level data thread safe. This can be done as below :

```
public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public synchronized void demoMethod(){} 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (this) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  private final Object lock = new Object(); 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (lock) 
 { 
  //other thread safe code 
 } 
}
```

**Class level locking:**

Class level locking prevents multiple threads to enter in synchronized block in any of all available instances on runtime. This means if in runtime there are 100 instances of DemoClass, then only one thread will be able to execute demoMethod() in any one of instance at a time, and all other instances will be locked for other threads. This should always be done to make static data thread safe.

```
public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public synchronized static void demoMethod(){} 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (DemoClass.class) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
 private final static Object lock = new Object(); 
 public void demoMethod(){ 
 synchronized (lock) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: "what is used as a mutex"?